# opscenter agent not connecting to opscenter

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

I am facing issue when I try to connect opscenter-agent to opscenter . In UI when we put any node ip it's shows `Error creating cluster: Timeout while adding cluster. Please check the log for details on the problem.`

In opscenter log I getting below error

```
2016-10-18 09:35:12+0000 [MW_Dev_Cluster]  WARN: Unable to collect datacenter, rack information: Failed query to http://10.164.120.116:61621/cluster/topology?node_ip=10.184.27.237 : [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone'>>]
2016-10-18 09:35:12+0000 [MW_Dev_Cluster]  WARN: HTTP request http://10.185.183.5:61621/cluster/topology?node_ip=10.112.73.35 failed: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone'>>]
```

In opscenter agent conf. file address.yaml only below entry is there

```
stomp_interface: "10.166.71.92"
```

Comment: What version of OpsCenter is this?

Comment: opscenter version is 3.2 and cassandra version is 1.0.9

Comment: Unfortunately OpsCenter 3.2 is incompatible with Cassandra 1.0. See the compatibility chart here: http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/4.0/opsc/opscUpgrading_g.html. You should use OpsCenter 3.1 with that version. You should also strongly consider upgrading both Cassandra and OpsCenter as those versions are quite old.

Comment: Yes I know that it's very old setup but for current situation I need to go with that .Can you able to share opscenter 3.1 and it's agent download link ?

Comment: I went to look and unfortunately it appears that OpsCenter 3.1 isn't available for download any longer.